# Ionic project from mac to windows

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm working on an ionic project , i dowloaded my coworker project from git , but the problem is , he is working on mac and im working on windows ,when i run ionic serve here's what i get :

```
> ng run app:serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8100
[ng] 'C:\Users\Louay Baccary\IonicWorkspace\SmartBeltIonic\node_modules\.bin\ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[ng] operable program or batch file.

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

Now i tried to npm run ng build , i get :

```
ERROR in ./src/global.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/global.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Error: Missing binding C:\Users\Louay Baccary\IonicWorkspace\SmartBeltIonic\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-64\binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Node.js 10.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - OS X 64-bit with Node.js 10.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
```

The terminal proposed npm rebuild node-sass i tried but no changes

Answer (score 0):

Try delete directory node_module and after run npm i